# Value of ISOcountryCode when not in a country? CLLocation / CLPlacemark,

Tags: objective-c, swift, cllocation, clplacemark

I am using locationManager and CLPlacemark to determine the ISO code of the country the user is in. It works great.

But I am unsure what the value is if the user is not in a country?

If a user is, for example, on a cruise halfway between Hawaii and Tahiti, then what is value of the ISOcountryCode property of a CLPlacemark? Is it nil? Or is there an "undefined" or "international space" value?

Comment: As the property is declared as an optional it's supposed to return `nil` in case the country could not be determined.

Comment: thanks vadian, however I wonder if there is a difference between not being able to determine the country, and being able to determine that there is no country?